# Extra characters in url after redirect successfully from foursquare using socialauth

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, foursquare, socialauth

I am using socialauth to have login with foursquare , when I do the authentication process I am successfully redirected to the success page but the url contains some extra characters how can I prevent it from coming in url

the url looks like

```
 http://localhost:8080/Project/authSuccess#_=_
```

I dont want to have

```
#_=_
```

in my url

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
window.location.href.split("#")[0]
```

This will give you url without hash fragment